# Number of Partitioning a deck with m cards in n types into n-element sets.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations, set-partition

For exsample,

There are 2cards in 3type. AA,BB,CC.

Partition 6cards into 2 3-element sets.

[AAB,BCC],[AAC,BBC],[ABB,ACC],[ABC,ABC],... 4 ways

or

Partition 6cards into 3 2-element sets.

[AA,BB,CC],[AA,BC,BC],[AB,AB,CC],[AB,AC,BC],[AC,AC,BB],... 5 ways

I find that
A002135 on oeis.org,
1,2,5,17,73,388,2461,.....
is the number of ways that 
a deck with 2 cards of each of n types 
may be dealt into n hands of 2 cards each.

But I want to know how to count number of ways that
a deck with m cards of each of n types
maybe dealt into n hands of m cards each 
and maybe dealt into m hands of n cards each.

I programed and count some numbers several ways.
But I can't know if what it's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the  number of elements  in each  of the inner  sets is $q.$  If I
understand correctly we are working with the unlabeled species
$$\mathfrak{M}_{=nm/q}(\mathfrak{M}_{=q}(\mathcal{Q}_1+
\mathcal{Q}_2+\mathcal{Q}_3+\mathcal{Q}_4+\cdots+\mathcal{Q}_n)).$$

It follows using the Polya Enumeration Theorem that the desired value
is given by
$$[Q_1^m Q_2^m Q_3^m \cdots Q_n^m]
Z(S_{nm/q})(Z(S_q)(Q_1+Q_2+Q_3+\cdots+Q_n))$$
where $Z(S_q)$ is the cycle index of the symmetric group.

This formula is of moderate  computational efficiency but it is exact.
We get for  two cards of $n$ types partitioned into $n$  hands of $2$
cards the sequence
$$1, 2, 5, 17, 73, 388, 2461, 18155, \ldots$$
which is indeed [OEIS A002135](https://oeis.org/A002135)
as noted by the OP.

For $n$ types and three cards per hand we get the sequence
$$1, 2, 10, 93, 1417, 32152, 1016489 \ldots$$

For $n$ types and four cards per hand we get the sequence
$$1, 3, 23, 465, 19834, 1532489, 193746632\ldots$$

I suspect there is something better that can be done, in which case
the above values can at least serve as proof of correctness.

If instead  we fix the number  of types we  get for two types  and two
cards per hand
$$1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, \ldots $$
and for three types with three cards per hand
$$1, 4, 10, 25, 49, 103, 184, 331, 554, 911, 1424, 2204, 3278,\ldots$$
and for four types with four cards per hand
$$1, 10, 70, 465, 2505, 12652, 57232, 240481, 936785, 3428138,\ldots$$

This computation was done with the following Maple code:

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
        local p, s;
        option remember;

        if n=0 then return 1; fi;

        expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

q :=
proc(n, m, q)
option remember;
    local tgf, gf1, gf2, k, res;

    if n*m mod q <> 0 then return FAIL fi;

    tgf := add(cat(`Q`, k), k=1..n);

    gf1 := expand(pet_varinto_cind
                  (tgf, pet_cycleind_symm(q)));
    gf2 := expand(pet_varinto_cind
                  (gf1, pet_cycleind_symm(n*m/q)));

    res := gf2;
    for k to n do
        res := coeff(res, cat(`Q`, k), m);
    od;

    res;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Mr.Marko Riedel.
And I found your paper "collier.pdf".
But I'm an japanese so I didn't knew and understood many mathematical term in english.
What are $_{=nm/q}$ and $Q_i$ mean?

Comment: The notation and some of the history of the method can be found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_combinatorics). Subscripts on combinatorial operators are understood to refer to the cardinality of the slots that the operator acts on. The operator $\mathfrak{M}_{=nm/q}$ is a multiset of $nm/q$ elements. The variables $\mathcal{Q}_i$ are placeholders for the different types of cards.